# "I hope you enjoyed the holidays and are having a great new year." Grammar Issues?

Tags: tenses, subjects

"I hope you enjoyed the holidays and are having a great new year."

Is this grammatically correct?
Firstly, there is a tense change. Possibly other problems.

Obviously this is correct: "I hope you enjoyed the holidays. I also hope you are having a great new year." But it's stilted beyond all stilted-ness. How do you combine the two sentiments into something natural?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the second option you gave (the supposedly stilted sentences.). It's clear and gets the job done.

Answer (score 3):

After the conjunction "and" you can change the tense.

Comment: so its two independent clauses that are linked together with the conjunction, right? "I hope you enjoyed the holidays" and "I hope you are having a great new year"... What about the omission of "I hope you" in the second clause? Is it implied?

Comment: @mark2020 Yes, it is implied..

Comment: Generally after a conjunction you can omit all the repeat words.  e.g. **I like to go skiing and I like to go fishing** can be truncated to **I like to go skiing and fishing**